# Windows C# Form: Prompt focus on a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering how would I auto select a textbox when using a Prompt on windows form. My code below shows what I have tried, but it is still focusing on the button and not the textbox. Thank you in advance for the help and assistance.

```
            Form prompt = new Form();
            prompt.Width = 500;
            prompt.Height = 200;
            prompt.Text = caption;
            Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
            Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 50, Width = 100, Top = 90 };
            confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
            textBox.Select();
            textBox.Focus();
            prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
            prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
            prompt.ShowDialog();
            return textBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait to focus the textbox until after the form is shown.  Before the form has been shown for the first time it is not *able* to focus anything.  You can use the `Shown` event to execute some code after the form is first shown.

```
string text = "Text";
string caption = "caption";
Form prompt = new Form();
prompt.Width = 500;
prompt.Height = 200;
prompt.Text = caption;
Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 50, Width = 100, Top = 90 };
confirmation.Click += (s, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
prompt.Shown += (s, e) => textBox.Focus();
prompt.ShowDialog();
return textBox.Text;
```

Comment: @AustinTruong Right you are, see edit (I tested it this time).